# Some CoreData objects are not showing up in relationship set

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship

I have a core data model setup with 3 entities: Plant, Recipe, and RecipePlant.

The Plant entity is populated with default data and is not editable by the user.  There are some pre-populated Recipes, but users are able to add their own recipes.

I'm using the RecipePlant entity because users are able to change some of the attributes of the plants they select for a recipe, but these changes are only for a recipe, they do not change the Plant entity.

Everything is working great, expect that I want to allow a user to create a RecipePlant without a relationship to a Plant.  This will allow them to create Recipes that include Plants not in the app's database.

When I try to add a "custom" RecipePlant object, it seems to work (no errors occur) but when I load the Recipe, it does not include these "custom" RecipePlant objects in the set.  Only the objects that have a relationship with a Plant object are included.

All of my relationships are set as optional.

How can I add a RecipePlant object to a Recipe object when the RecipePlant does not have a relationship with a Plant object?

Comment: Are you saving your data? Can you show an image of this piece of your model in the editor?

Comment: @Paul.s Is this what you're looking for? http://i.imgur.com/mXIgmEg.png

Comment: Can you show the creation code...

Comment: When going through my code to update my question, I discovered my problem.  I wasn't actually added the new RecipePlant object to the plants set of the Recipe object!